# Heroku Rails Memory exceed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I've developed web site using Ruby on rails.
But i have a serious problems.

1. Increasing continuously Heroku memory usage.
2. Heroku Response Time is too long sometimes.

I've tried a lot to solve this problem.

1. When visit user list page Without activerecord query execution, there is no memory increasing.
2. When visit user list page 20 times in normal, there is memory increasing.
3. So I added tunemygc gem for garbage collecting and tested. But no impaction.

So i think this Reasons of Memory issues are

1. Rails has such issue.
2. Dependencies of activerecord is not going well or there is bad dependency.

Does anyone knows the way to solve this problem.

1. Want to test the app by virtualizing requests ike as user does. Any idea?
2. Want to solve the memory issues clearly. Any ideas?
3. Does this solve by setting Heroku server configuration properly?

Comment: Does the memory consumption stabilize after some time (for example 24 hours)? How much memory does your application use right after deploy? Which dyno type are you using? How many requests does your application usually have per minute?

Comment: I'm using Hobby web dyno.

Comment: After deploy, my application use 200 mb.
But after many users has done a job on my web application, memory usage increase over 1GB.
I don't know exactly the requests count per minute.
But i can say max requests is about 200.
Thanks.